# How to inject individual touches on Windows 8.1 C++

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, multi-touch

I have been trying to inject individual contacts (Touch events) on Windows 8. I'm using the InjectTouchInput described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802881(v=vs.85).aspx), so I'm able to inject two contacts with the next code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class calculate
{
    POINTER_TOUCH_INFO contact[2];

public:
    calculate(int m);
    void setDots(long x, long y, long x2, long y2, int opt, string num_dots);
};

calculate::calculate(int m)
{
}

void calculate::setDots(long x, long y, long x2, long y2, int opt, string num_dots)
{

    switch (opt)
    {
        case 0:
            InitializeTouchInjection(2, TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT);
            memset(&contact[0], 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));
            memset(&contact[1], 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));

            contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH;
            contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerId = 0;          //Id 0 for contact 0
            contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = y;
            contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = x;

            contact[0].touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE;
            contact[0].touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE;
            contact[0].orientation = 90;
            contact[0].pressure = 32000;
            contact[0].rcContact.top = contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 2;
            contact[0].rcContact.bottom = contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
            contact[0].rcContact.left = contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  - 2;
            contact[0].rcContact.right = contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  + 2;

            contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerId = 1;          //Id 0 for contact 1
            contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = y2;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = x2;

            contact[1].touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE;
            contact[1].touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE;
            contact[1].orientation = 90;
            contact[1].pressure = 32000;
            contact[1].rcContact.top = contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 2;
            contact[1].rcContact.bottom = contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
            contact[1].rcContact.left = contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  - 2;
            contact[1].rcContact.right = contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  + 2;
        break;
        case 1: 
            contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = y;
            contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = x;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = y2;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = x2;
            contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
        break;
        case 2:
            /*if I inject this flag to first contact [0], both points stopped, but I'm able to inject this flag to the second contact [1] and all is OK*/
            //contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UP;

            contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
            //contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerId = 0;  
            //contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerId = 1;   
            contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x =x;
            contact[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y =y;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x =x2;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y =y2;
            //num_dots = "single";
        break;
        case 3:
            contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UP;
            contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UP;
        break;
    }

    bool s;
    //check how many points to inject
    if(num_dots == "single")
        s = InjectTouchInput(1, contact);
    else
        s = InjectTouchInput(2, contact);

    if(!s)
    {
        LPWSTR str = new wchar_t[255];
        auto t = GetLastError();
        wsprintf(str, L"error: %d\n", t);
        OutputDebugString(str);
        wsprintf(str, L" action: %d\n", opt);
        OutputDebugString(str);
    }
    else
    {
        LPWSTR str = new wchar_t[255];
        auto t = GetLastError();
        wsprintf(str, L"action %d\n", opt);
        OutputDebugString(str);
    }
    if(opt == 2)
        Sleep(20);
}


int c =0;
int
WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd)
{

    bool g = true;
    POINT ipoint;
    POINT point;
    calculate set(0);
    if (GetCursorPos(&ipoint)) 
        set.setDots(ipoint.x, ipoint.y, 0,0,0, "single");//initialize both points


    do
    {

        if (GetCursorPos(&point)) {   

            //stop the loop pressing right click
            if((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0)
                g = false;
            if((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0)
            {
                if(c<1)
                {                   

                    if((GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x100) != 0)//injecting DOWN event
                        set.setDots(point.x, point.y, point.x - 50, point.y + 50, 1, "two");
                    else
                        set.setDots(point.x, point.y, 0, 0, 1, "single");
                }
                else
                {
                    if((GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x100) != 0)//injecting UPDATE event (on move)
                        set.setDots(point.x, point.y, point.x - 50, point.y + 50, 2, "two");
                    else
                        set.setDots(point.x, point.y, 0,0,2, "single");
                }
                c++;
            }
            else
            {
                /*if((GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x100) != 0)
                    set.setDots(0,0,0,0,3, "two");
                else
                    set.setDots(0,0,0,0,3, "single");*/
                c = 0;
            }     
        }
    } while (g);


}
```

So, with this code, I'm able to inject one or two touches (if shift key is pressed), and draw on paint using paint brushes. But when I try to inject individual events for each contact, for example `contact[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UP;
contact[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;` both contacts stop, even when I try changing their ids, or changing the number of points to inject.

The above code is just an example, but I have tried using different flags for each contact without success :(

My goal is be able to inject two points, with individual events each one, and if first contact[0] has an UP event, the second contact should still running without stop the process...So, how can I inject individual contacts (touches) with different events each one?

Thank you!